# Azure AD B2C: ROPC - Release Date Question

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have created a prototype using ROPC custom policy in Azure AD B2C.  It is currently marked as "Preview".  Is there an approximate release date for this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been working well during the preview.
Our plan is to GA this during the first quarter of 2019 (Jan-Mar).  At this time we foresee no changes necessary before General Availability.   Please provide any feedback on your experience to: aadb2cpreview@microsoft.com

Thank you,
Jose

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this feature about the custom policy is already released by using the Identity Experience Framework. For the details, you could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-developer-notes-custom).

Comment: If there is anything update, please let me know, thanks!